# Husky pre-commit doesn't fire in create-react app

Tags: git, create-react-app, husky

I installed husky to automatically format my code as [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#formatting-code-automatically) say. When I try to commit files, pre-commit actions just don't fire and **non-formatted files are committed**. What can I do with that?

I didn't do anything connected with Prettier or Husky that is not written in CRA docs: only installed prettier, husky, and lint-staged and added some code in package.json. Also I saw some similar questions there, but the answers are mostly connected with Node and Git versions and it's not my case.

**Node** version: `v14.17.5`
**Git** version: `2.32.0.windows.2`

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "ts-react-course",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "types": "^0.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Husky's [API has dropped conventional JS configuration support](https://blog.typicode.com/husky-git-hooks-javascript-config/) and `create-react-app`'s documentation is outdated as it shows the old way of configuring it. When you installed Husky with `npm install husky` you installed the latest Husky version and not the old version.

##### Proposed solution

```sh
npx husky install
npm set-script prepare "husky install"
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"
```

Here's the associated GitHub issue in `create-react-app` repository in case you like to stay up-to-date with the fix: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11568